# Salesforce Schedulable not working

Tags: salesforce

I have several HTTP callouts that are in a schedulable and set to run ever hour or so. After I deployed the app on the app exchange and had a salesforce user download it to test, it seems the jobs are not executing.

I can see the jobs are being scheduled to run accordingly however the database never seems to change. Is there any reason this could be happening or is there a good chance the flaw lies in my code?

I was thinking that it could be permissions however I am not sure (its the first app I am deploying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the organisation of your end user has added your endpoint to "remote site settings" in the setup. By endpoint I mean an address that's being called (or just the domain).

If the class is scheduled properly (which I believe would be a manual action, not just something that magically happens after installation... unless you've used a post-install script?) you could also examine Setup -> Apex Jobs and check if there are any errors. If I'm right, there will be an error about callout not allowed due to remote site settings. If not - there's still a chance you'll see something that will make you think. For example batch job has executed successfully but there were 0 iterations -> problem?

Last but not least - you can always try the debug logs :) Enable them in Setup (or open the developer console), fire the scheduled class's `execute()` manually and observe the results? How to fire it manually? Sth like this pasted to "execute anonymous":

```
MySchedulableClass sched = new MySchedubulableClass();
sched.execute(null);
```

Or - since you know what's inside the scheduled class - simply experiment.

Please note that if the updates you might be performing somehow violate for example validation rules your client has - yes, the database will be unchanged. But in such case you should still be able to see failures in Setup -> Apex Jobs.